# Cannot use LESS on localhost

Tags: javascript, cors, less

I am trying to use LESS 1.1.3 on localhost and it's not working.
Below is my error.

> less-1.1.3.min.js:28 XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/rasarouting/site/templates/styles/fixed2.less.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http,
>   data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
>
> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest':
>   Failed to load
>   'file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/rasarouting/site/templates/styles/fixed2.less'.
>       at r (file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/rasarouting/site/templates/javascript/less-1.1.3.min.js:28:2626)
>       at o (file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/rasarouting/site/templates/javascript/less-1.1.3.min.js:28:3825)
>       at n (file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/rasarouting/site/templates/javascript/less-1.1.3.min.js:28:4368)
>       at Object.d.refresh (file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/rasarouting/site/templates/javascript/less-1.1.3.min.js:29:1545)
>       at file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/rasarouting/site/templates/javascript/less-1.1.3.min.js:29:1830
>       at file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/rasarouting/site/templates/javascript/less-1.1.3.min.js:29:1862

What is going on? It works online, why not on localhost?

Comment: Browsers are not allowed to access `file:` resources by default

Comment: So how am I supposed to design my website? It doesn't work on file:// and localhost

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10752078/1063093

Comment: The answer works but my less file isn't being recognised by my localhost so I'll ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you're not allowed to use the file:// protocol. This is for security. It appears you have XAMPP installed, you should be able to access these files by sending an http request to `localhost:[port]/rasarouting/site/templates/javascript/less-1.1.3.min.js`

Comment: Your answer gives me an `net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME` error even though I entered the correct address for the javascript.

Comment: @desbest what url are you sending the request to? you are going to need an http:// before that and you will need to replace [port] with the port you are running on.